# Wordpress Admin Filters - how do I load option by default?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am modifying a script for a plugin, and my problem is that I want it to filter only one option by default when the page loads. It has three options:

1) All
2) Current
3) Past

I only want the Current listings to show and not the past or "All"... I have the script below...

```
<?php
/**
 * Admin functions for the ajde_events post type
 *
 * @author      AJDE
 * @category    Admin
 * @package     eventON/Admin/ajde_events
 * @version     2.4.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly


class evo_ajde_events{
    public function __construct(){
        add_filter( 'manage_edit-ajde_events_columns', array($this,'eventon_edit_event_columns') );

        // custom filters
        add_action('restrict_manage_posts',array($this,'evo_restrict_manage_posts'));
        add_filter('query_vars', array($this,'wpse57344_register_query_vars' ));
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array($this,'wpse57351_pre_get_posts' ));

        add_action('manage_ajde_events_posts_custom_column', array($this,'eventon_custom_event_columns'), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'manage_edit-ajde_events_sortable_columns', array($this,'eventon_custom_events_sort'));
        add_filter( 'request', array($this,'eventon_custom_event_orderby') );

        add_filter( 'list_table_primary_column', array( $this, 'list_table_primary_column' ), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'post_row_actions', array($this,'eventon_duplicate_event_link_row'),10,2 );
        add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', array($this,'eventon_duplicate_event_post_button') );

        add_action( 'quick_edit_custom_box',  array($this,'eventon_admin_event_quick_edit'), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'eventon_admin_events_quick_edit_scripts'), 10 );
        add_action( 'save_post', array($this,'eventon_admin_event_quick_edit_save'), 10, 2 );
    }

    // Columns for events page
        function eventon_edit_event_columns( $existing_columns ) {
            global $eventon;

            // GET event type custom names
            $evcal_opt1= get_option('evcal_options_evcal_1');
            $evt_name = (!empty($evcal_opt1['evcal_eventt']))?$evcal_opt1['evcal_eventt']:'Event Type';
            $evt_name2 = (!empty($evcal_opt1['evcal_eventt2']))?$evcal_opt1['evcal_eventt2']:'Event Type 2';

            if ( empty( $existing_columns ) && ! is_array( $existing_columns ) )
                $existing_columns = array();

            unset( $existing_columns['title'], $existing_columns['comments'], $existing_columns['date'] );

            $columns = array();
            $columns["cb"] = "<input type=\"checkbox\" />";

            $columns["name"] = __( 'Event Name', 'eventon' );

            $columns["event_location"] = __( 'Location', 'eventon' );
            $columns["event_type"] = __( $evt_name, 'eventon' );
            $columns["event_type_2"] = __( $evt_name2, 'eventon' );
            $columns["event_start_date"] = __( 'Start Date', 'eventon' );
            $columns["event_end_date"] = __( 'End Date', 'eventon' );
            $columns["evo_featured"] = '<img src="' . AJDE_EVCAL_URL . '/assets/images/icons/featured.png" title="' . __( 'Featured', 'eventon' ) . '" title="' . __( 'Featured', 'eventon' ) . '" width="12" height="12" />';
            $columns["repeat"] = '<img src="' . AJDE_EVCAL_URL . '/assets/images/icons/evo_repeat.png" alt="' . __( 'Event Repeat', 'eventon' ) . '" title="' . __( 'Event Repeat', 'eventon' ) . '" class="tips" />';
            //$columns["date"] = __( 'Date', 'eventon' );

            $columns = apply_filters('evo_event_columns', $columns);    

            return array_merge( $columns, $existing_columns );
        }

    // Custom filters for all events
        function evo_restrict_manage_posts() {
            global $typenow;

            if ($typenow=='ajde_events'){
                $event_date_type = (isset($_GET['event_date_type'])? $_GET['event_date_type']:null);
                ?>
                <select name="event_date_type">
                    <option value="all"><?php _e('All Events','eventon');?></option>
                    <option value="past" <?php echo ($event_date_type=='past')?"selected='selected'":'';?>><?php _e('Past Events','eventon');?></option>
                    <option value="live" selected="selected" <?php echo ($event_date_type=='live')?"selected='selected'":'';?>><?php _e('Current Events','eventon');?></option>
                </select>
                <?php
            }
        }
        function wpse57344_register_query_vars( $qvars ){
            //Add these query variables
            $qvars[] = 'event_date_type';
            return $qvars;
        }
        function wpse57351_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

            //Only alter query if custom variable is set.
            $event_date_type = $query->get('event_date_type');
            if( !empty($event_date_type) ){

                 //Be careful not override any existing meta queries.
                $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
                if( empty($meta_query) )
                    $meta_query = array();

                //Get posts with date between the first and last of given month
                date_default_timezone_set('UTC');   
                $timenow = current_time('timestamp');


                if($event_date_type=='past'){
                    $meta_query[] = array(
                        'key' => 'evcal_erow',
                        'value' => $timenow,
                        'compare' => '<',
                    );
                }elseif($event_date_type=='live'){
                    $meta_query[] = array(
                        'key' => 'evcal_erow',
                        'value' => $timenow,
                        'compare' => '>=',
                    );
                }

                $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
            }
        }

    // Custom Columns for event page
        function eventon_custom_event_columns( $column , $post_id) {
            global $post, $eventon;

            //if ( empty( $ajde_events ) || $ajde_events->id != $post->ID )
                //$ajde_events = get_product( $post );
            $pmv = get_post_custom($post->ID);

            switch ($column) {
                case has_filter("evo_column_type_{$column}"):
                        $content = apply_filters("evo_column_type_{$column}", $post_id);
                        echo $content;
                    break;
                case "thumb" :
                    //echo '<a href="' . get_edit_post_link( $post->ID ) . '">' . $ajde_events->get_image() . '</a>';
                break;

                case "name" :
                    $edit_link = get_edit_post_link( $post->ID );
                    $title = _draft_or_post_title();
                    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
                    $can_edit_post = current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->edit_post, $post->ID );


                    echo "<div class='evoevent_item'>";
                        $img_src = $eventon->evo_admin->get_image('thumbnail',false);
                        $event_color = eventon_get_hex_color($pmv);
                        echo '<a class="evoevent_image" href="' . get_edit_post_link( $post_id ) . '">';
                        if($img_src){
                            echo '<img class="evoEventCirc" src="' . $img_src . '"/>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<span class="evoEventCirc" style="background-color:' . $event_color . '"></span>';
                        }
                        echo '</a>';

                    echo '<div class="evo_item_details">';


                    if($can_edit_post){
                        echo '<strong><a class="row-title" href="'.$edit_link.'">' . $title.'</a>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<strong>' . $title.'';
                    }

                    _post_states( $post );

                    echo '</strong>';

                    if ( $post->post_parent > 0 )
                        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&larr; <a href="'. get_edit_post_link($post->post_parent) .'">'. get_the_title($post->post_parent) .'</a>';

                    // Excerpt view
                    if (isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode']=='excerpt') echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt);

                    // Get actions
                        $actions = array();

                        $actions['id'] = 'ID: ' . $post->ID;

                        if ( $can_edit_post && 'trash' != $post->post_status ) {
                            $actions['edit'] = '<a href="' . get_edit_post_link( $post->ID, true ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( __( 'Edit this item' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Edit' ) . '</a>';
                            $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] = '<a href="#" class="editinline" title="' . esc_attr( __( 'Edit this item inline' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Quick&nbsp;Edit' ) . '</a>';
                        }
                        if ( current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->delete_post, $post->ID ) ) {
                            if ( 'trash' == $post->post_status )
                                $actions['untrash'] = "<a title='" . esc_attr( __( 'Restore this item from the Trash' ) ) . "' href='" . wp_nonce_url( admin_url( sprintf( $post_type_object->_edit_link . '&amp;action=untrash', $post->ID ) ), 'untrash-post_' . $post->ID ) . "'>" . __( 'Restore' ) . "</a>";
                            elseif ( EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS )
                                $actions['trash'] = "<a class='submitdelete' title='" . esc_attr( __( 'Move this item to the Trash' ) ) . "' href='" . get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ) . "'>" . __( 'Trash' ) . "</a>";
                            if ( 'trash' == $post->post_status || !EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS )
                                $actions['delete'] = "<a class='submitdelete' title='" . esc_attr( __( 'Delete this item permanently' ) ) . "' href='" . get_delete_post_link( $post->ID, '', true ) . "'>" . __( 'Delete Permanently' ) . "</a>";
                        }
                        if ( $post_type_object->public ) {
                            if ( in_array( $post->post_status, array( 'pending', 'draft', 'future' ) ) ) {
                                if ( $can_edit_post )
                                    $actions['view'] = '<a href="' . esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Preview &#8220;%s&#8221;' ), $title ) ) . '" rel="permalink">' . __( 'Preview' ) . '</a>';
                            } elseif ( 'trash' != $post->post_status ) {
                                $actions['view'] = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View &#8220;%s&#8221;' ), $title ) ) . '" rel="permalink">' . __( 'View' ) . '</a>';
                            }
                        }

                        $actions = apply_filters( 'post_row_actions', $actions, $post );

                    // ROW ACTIONS
                        echo '<div class="evo_row_actions row-actions">';
                            $i = 0;
                            $action_count = sizeof($actions);

                            foreach ( $actions as $action => $link ) {
                                ++$i;
                                ( $i == $action_count ) ? $sep = '' : $sep = ' | ';
                                echo "<span class='$action'>$link$sep</span>";
                            }
                        echo '</div>';

                    get_inline_data( $post );

                    $event = $eventon->evo_event_item->get_event($post->ID);

                    //print_r($event);

                    /* Custom inline data for eventon */
                    echo '<div class="hidden" id="eventon_inline_' . $post->ID . '">';
                    foreach($eventon->evo_event_item->get_event_fields_edit()  as $field){
                        $value = (!empty($event->$field))? $event->$field: null;
                        echo "<div class='{$field}'>{$value}</div>";
                    }
                    echo "<div class='_menu_order'>".$post->menu_order."</div>";
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div><!--.evoevent_item-->';

                break;

                case "event_type" :     
                    if ( ! $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $column ) ) {
                        echo '<span class="na">&ndash;</span>';
                    } else {
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            $termlist[] = '<a href="' . admin_url( 'edit.php?' . $column . '=' . $term->slug . '&post_type=ajde_events' ) . ' ">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        }

                        echo implode( ', ', $termlist );
                    }
                break;
                case "event_type_2" :       
                    if ( ! $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $column ) ) {
                        echo '<span class="na">&ndash;</span>';
                    } else {
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            $termlist[] = '<a href="' . admin_url( 'edit.php?' . $column . '=' . $term->slug . '&post_type=ajde_events' ) . ' ">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        }

                        echo implode( ', ', $termlist );
                    }
                break;
                case "event_location":

                    if ( ! $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $column ) ) {
                        echo '<span class="na">&ndash;</span>';
                    } else {
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            $termlist[] = '<a href="' . admin_url( 'edit.php?' . $column . '=' . $term->slug . '&post_type=ajde_events' ) . ' ">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        }

                        echo implode( ', ', $termlist );
                    }

                break;  

                case "event_start_date":

                    if(evo_check_yn($pmv, 'evo_year_long')){
                        echo date('Y', $pmv['evcal_srow'][0]);
                    }elseif(evo_check_yn($pmv, '_evo_month_long')){
                        echo date_i18n('F, Y', $pmv['evcal_srow'][0]);
                    }else{
                        if(!empty($pmv['evcal_srow'])){
                            $_START = eventon_get_editevent_kaalaya($pmv['evcal_srow'][0]);
                            if(evo_check_yn($pmv, 'evcal_allday')){
                                echo $_START[0]. ' -'. __('All Day','eventon');
                            }else{
                                echo $_START[0].' - '.$_START[1].':'.$_START[2]. (!empty($_START[3])? $_START[3]:'');
                            }       


                        }else{  echo "--";  }   
                    }                   

                break;      

                case "event_end_date":  

                    if(evo_check_yn($pmv, 'evo_year_long')){
                        echo date('Y', $pmv['evcal_srow'][0]);
                    }elseif(evo_check_yn($pmv, '_evo_month_long')){
                        echo date_i18n('F, Y', $pmv['evcal_srow'][0]);
                    }else{
                        if(!empty($pmv['evcal_erow'])){ 
                            $_END = eventon_get_editevent_kaalaya($pmv['evcal_erow'][0]);       
                            if(evo_check_yn($pmv, 'evcal_allday')){
                                echo $_END[0]. ' -'. __('All Day','eventon');
                            }else{
                                echo $_END[0].' - '.$_END[1].':'.$_END[2]. (!empty($_END[3])? $_END[3]:'');
                            }   
                        }else{  echo "--";  }
                    }       
                break;

                case "evo_featured":

                    $url = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=eventon-feature-event&eventID=' . $post->ID ), 'eventon-feature-event' );
                    echo '<a href="' . $url . '" title="'. __( 'Toggle featured', 'eventon' ) . '">';
                    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured', true)=='yes' ) {
                        echo '<img src="' . AJDE_EVCAL_URL . '/assets/images/icons/featured.png" title="'. __( 'Yes', 'eventon' ) . '" height="14" width="14" />';
                    } else {
                        echo '<img src="' . AJDE_EVCAL_URL . '/assets/images/icons/featured-off.png" title="'. __( 'No', 'eventon' ) . '" height="14" width="14" />';
                    }
                    echo '</a>';

                    //echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured', true);     
                break;

                case 'repeat':

                    $repeat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'evcal_repeat',true);        

                    if(!empty($repeat) && $repeat=='yes'){
                        $repeat_freq = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'evcal_rep_freq',true);
                        $output_repeat = '<span>'.$repeat_freq.'</span>';
                    }else{
                        $output_repeat = '<span class="na">&ndash;</span>';
                    }

                    echo $output_repeat;
                break;
            }
        }
        function eventon_custom_events_sort($columns) {
            $custom = array(
                'event_start_date'      => 'evcal_start_date',
                'event_end_date'        => 'evcal_end_date',
                'event_location'        => 'event_location',
                'name'                  => 'title',
                'evo_featured'          => 'featured',
                //'repeat'              => 'repeat',
            );
            return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
        }
        function eventon_custom_event_orderby( $vars ) {
            if (isset( $vars['orderby'] )) :
                if ( 'evcal_start_date' == $vars['orderby'] ) :
                    $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
                        'meta_key'  => 'evcal_srow',
                        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num'
                    ) );
                endif;
                if ( 'evcal_end_date' == $vars['orderby'] ) :
                    $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
                        'meta_key'  => 'evcal_erow',
                        'orderby'   => 'meta_value'
                    ) );
                endif;
                if ( 'featured' == $vars['orderby'] ) :
                    $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
                        'meta_key'  => '_featured',
                        'orderby'   => 'meta_value'
                    ) );
                endif;
                if ( 'event_location' == $vars['orderby'] ) :
                    $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
                        'meta_key'  => 'evcal_location',
                        'orderby'   => 'meta_value'
                    ) );
                endif;
            endif;

            return $vars;
        }

    // Set list table primary column for events
        function list_table_primary_column( $default, $screen_id ) {

            if ( 'edit-ajde_events' === $screen_id ) {
                return 'name';
            }

            return $default;
        }

    // Duplicate event
        function eventon_duplicate_event_link_row($actions, $post) {

            if ( function_exists( 'duplicate_post_plugin_activation' ) ) return $actions;

            if ( $post->post_type != 'ajde_events' )    return $actions;

            $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

            if ( current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post->ID ) ){

                $actions['duplicate'] = '<a href="' . wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin.php?action=duplicate_event&amp;post=' . $post->ID ), 'eventon-duplicate-event_' . $post->ID ) . '" title="' . __( 'Make a duplicate from this event', 'eventon' )
                . '" rel="permalink">' .  __( 'Duplicate', 'eventon' ) . '</a>';
            }

            return $actions;
        }
        function eventon_duplicate_event_post_button() {
            global $post;

            if ( function_exists( 'duplicate_post_plugin_activation' ) ) return;

            if ( ! is_object( $post ) ) return;

            if ( $post->post_type != 'ajde_events' ) return;

            if ( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
                $notifyUrl = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( "admin.php?action=duplicate_event&post=" . absint( $_GET['post'] ) ), 'eventon-duplicate-event_' . $_GET['post'] );
                ?>
                <div class="misc-pub-section" >
                    <div id="duplicate-action"><a class="submitduplicate duplication button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $notifyUrl ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Duplicate this event', 'eventon' ); ?></a></div>

                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }

    // Custom quick edit - form
        function eventon_admin_events_quick_edit_scripts( $hook ) {
            global $eventon, $post_type;

            if ( $hook == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'ajde_events' )
                wp_enqueue_script( 'eventon_quick-edit', AJDE_EVCAL_URL. '/assets/js/admin/quick-edit.js', array('jquery') );
        }
        function eventon_admin_event_quick_edit( $column_name, $post_type ) {
            if ($column_name != 'event_start_date' || $post_type != 'ajde_events') return;

                $evcal_date_format = eventon_get_time_format('24');

                global $ajde;
            ?>
            <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-left">
                <div id="eventon-fields" class="inline-edit-col">

                    <legend class='inline-edit-legend'><?php _e( 'Event Data', 'eventon' ); ?></legend>

                    <div class="event_fields inline-edit-col">
                        <input type='hidden' name='_evo_date_format' value=''/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='_evo_time_format' value=''/>
                        <label>
                            <span class="title"><?php _e( 'Start Date', 'eventon' ); ?></span>
                            <span class="input-text-wrap">
                                <input type="text" name="evcal_start_date" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Event Start Date', 'eventon' ); ?>" value="">
                            </span>
                        </label>    
                        <label>
                            <span class="title"><?php _e( 'Start Time', 'eventon' ); ?></span>
                            <span class="input-text-wrap">
                                <span class='input_time'>
                                    <input type="text" name="evcal_start_time_hour" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Event Start Hour', 'eventon' ); ?>" value="">
                                    <em>Hr</em>
                                </span>
                                <span class='input_time'>
                                    <input type="text" name="evcal_start_time_min" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Event Start Minutes', 'eventon' ); ?>" value="">
                                    <em>Min</em>
                                </span>
                                <?php if($evcal_date_format=='12h'):?>
                                <span class='input_time'>
                                    <input type="text" name="evcal_st_ampm" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Event Start AM/PM', 'eventon' ); ?>" value="">
                                    <em>AM/PM</em>
                                </span>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </span>
                        </label>

                        <?php // end time date?>
                        <label>
                            <span class="title"><?php _e( 'End Date', 'eventon' ); ?></span>
                            <span class="input-text-wrap">
                                <input type="text" name="evcal_end_date" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Event End Date', 'eventon' ); ?>" value="">
                            </span>
                        </label>    
                        <label>
                            <span class="title"><?php _e( 'End Time', 'eventon' ); ?></span>
                            <span class="input-text-wrap">
                                <span class='input_time'>
                                    <input type="text" name="evcal_end_time_hour" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Event End Hour', 'eventon' ); ?>" value="">
                                    <em>Hr</em>
                                </span>
                                <span class='input_time'>
                                    <input type="text" name="evcal_end_time_min" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Event End Minutes', 'eventon' ); ?>" value="">
                                    <em>Min</em>
                                </span>
                                <?php if($evcal_date_format=='12h'):?>
                                <span class='input_time'>
                                    <input type="text" name="evcal_et_ampm" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Event End AM/PM', 'eventon' ); ?>" value="">
                                    <em>AM/PM</em>
                                </span>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </span>
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <span class="title"><?php _e( 'Subtitle', 'eventon' ); ?></span>
                            <span class="input-text-wrap">
                                <input type="text" name="evcal_subtitle" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Event Sub Title', 'eventon' ); ?>" value="">
                            </span>
                        </label>

                        <?php

                            $fields = array(
                                'evcal_allday'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'yesno',
                                    'label'=>__('All day event','eventon')
                                ),
                                'evo_hide_endtime'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'yesno',
                                    'label'=>__('Hide end time from calendar','eventon')
                                ),                              
                                '_featured'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'yesno',
                                    'label'=>__('Featured event','eventon')
                                ),
                                'evo_exclude_ev'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'yesno',
                                    'label'=>__('Exclude from calendar','eventon')
                                ),
                                'location'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'subheader',
                                    'label'=>__('Location Data','eventon')
                                ),
                                'evcal_gmap_gen'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'yesno',
                                    'label'=>__('Generate google map from the address','eventon')
                                ),
                                'evcal_hide_locname'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'yesno',
                                    'label'=>__('Hide location name from the event card','eventon')
                                ),
                                'evo_access_control_location'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'yesno',
                                    'label'=>__('Make location information only visible to logged-in users','eventon')
                                ),
                                'organizer'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'subheader',
                                    'label'=>__('Organizer Data','eventon')
                                ),
                                'evo_evcrd_field_org'=> array(
                                    'type'=>'yesno',
                                    'label'=>__('Hide organizer field from event card','eventon')
                                ),
                            );

                            foreach($fields as $field=>$val){
                                switch($val['type']){
                                    case 'yesno': ?>
                                        <p class="yesno_row evo">
                                        <?php
                                            echo $ajde->wp_admin->html_yesnobtn(array(
                                                'id'=>$field,
                                                'label'=> $val['label'],
                                                'input'=>true
                                            ));
                                        ?>
                                        </p>    
                                    <?php
                                    break;
                                    case 'subheader':
                                        ?><p><?php echo $val['label'];?></p><?php
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        ?>

                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="eventon_quick_edit_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'eventon_quick_edit_nonce' ); ?>" />

                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <?php
        }

        // SAVE QUICK EDIT
        function eventon_admin_event_quick_edit_save( $post_id, $post ) {

            if ( ! $_POST || is_int( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) || is_int( wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) ) return $post_id;
            if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
            if ( ! isset( $_POST['eventon_quick_edit_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventon_quick_edit_nonce'], 'eventon_quick_edit_nonce' ) ) return $post_id;
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return $post_id;
            if ( $post->post_type != 'ajde_events' ) return $post_id;

            global $eventon, $wpdb;

            // Save fields
            if ( isset( $_POST['evcal_subtitle'] ) ) 
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'evcal_subtitle', eventon_clean( $_POST['evcal_subtitle'] ) );


            $proper_time =  evoadmin_get_unix_time_fromt_post($post_id);

            // start time
            //$proper_time = eventon_get_unix_time();   
            // full time converted to unix time stamp
            if ( !empty($proper_time['unix_start']) )
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'evcal_srow', $proper_time['unix_start']);

            if ( !empty($proper_time['unix_end']) )
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'evcal_erow', $proper_time['unix_end']);


            foreach( apply_filters('eventon_quick_save_fields', array(
                '_featured',
                'evo_hide_endtime',
                'evcal_allday',
                'evo_exclude_ev',
                'evcal_gmap_gen',
                'evcal_hide_locname',
                'evo_access_control_location',
                'evo_evcrd_field_org',
            )) as $field){
                if( !isset($_POST[ $field ])) continue;
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $field, $_POST[ $field ]  );
            }


            // menu order
            if( isset( $_POST['_menu_order'] ) ){               
                $newpostdata['menu_order'] = 5;
                $newpostdata['ID'] = $post_id;
                //wp_update_post($newpostdata);
            }
        }
}
new evo_ajde_events();

?>
```

[image]

Again, I would like for that "Current" to be the default and load with that page... please tell me that this is possible, because I would like to get that working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `all` and the `past` filters in the dropdown try removing the options in the dropdown element.

```
<select name="event_date_type">
  <option value="live" selected="selected" <?php echo ($event_date_type=='live')?"selected='selected'":'';?>><?php _e('Current Events','eventon');?></option>
</select>
```

Beware to remove this conditional too and replace the `elseif` with a single `if`

```
if($event_date_type=='past'){
   $meta_query[] = array(
     'key' => 'evcal_erow',
     'value' => $timenow,
     'compare' => '<',
 );
```

Comment: I tried each of those at the beginning and it still loaded **"all"** which included the past. That's what confused me because it seemed clearcut, but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear: I can remove the items from the dropdowns, but it would not LOAD with the options. I would like for the page to load with "Current" listings already filtered out.